# Output file name not being correctly named for Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The file name format is like this: 4digitnumber_S_R1_001.fastq.gz.
To give you an example 3145_S2_R1_001.fastq.gz
I'm trying to have my output file name not include `_R1_001` part but it keeps including the full file name. I am not sure why it's not giving me the correct output file name format that I want.
Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the input directory containing .fastq.gz files
input_dir="/storage/home/user/work/fastq_data"

# Set the output directory for .sam and summary files
output_dir="/storage/home/user/work/fastq_data/gene_alignment"

# Create the output directory if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$output_dir"

# Get the full path of the output directory
output_dir="/storage/home/user/work/fastq_data/gene_alignment"


# Use find to iterate over .fastq.gz files in the input directory
find "${input_dir}" -type f -name "*.fastq.gz" | while read -r input_file; do
  # Remove the directory path and extension to get the base file name
  base_name=$(basename "$input_file" .fastq.gz)

  # Remove "_R_001" from the base_name using awk
  new_name=$(echo "$base_name" | awk -F '_R_001' '{print $1}')

  # Construct the output file names
  output_sam="${output_dir}/${new_name}.sam"
  summary_file="${output_dir}/${new_name}.summary"

  # Run HISAT2
  hisat2 -p 8 -x musculus_index -U "${input_file}" -S "${output_sam}" --dta-cufflinks 2>&1 | tee "${summary_file}"

  echo "Processed ${input_file}"
done

echo "Processing complete."
```

I tried various ways to have `new_name =`, for my output file names, using `sed` or `"${base_name/_R_001/}"` etc.
Not sure where I am getting it wrong. Would appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the content of `base_name`? In your initial example you use `3145_S2_R1_001`, but in the awk statement, you use `_R_001` as field separator, which is not contained in the basename. Aside from this, using `awk` for this purpose is an overkill. You can manipulate the string using bash parameter substitution and/or bash regular expressions.

Comment: You don't need sed or awk for that, all you need is `new_name="${base_name/_R1_001}"`. Please reduce your code to a **minimal** example, e.g. 3 lines, that can reproduce just the problem you're asking about, i.e. how to populate `new_name` from `$base_name`. Whatever problem your code has we can't easily see it due to all of the irrelevant code around the couple of lines where the problem actually occurs.

Comment: Chances are that by trying to create the [mcve] to post in your question you'll figure out the answer to the problem yourself.

Comment: @EdMorton I tried using just `new_name="${base_name/_R1_001}` but it will still spit out `_R1_001` in the output file name. That was the first attempt before I tried other ways to get rid of those but keeps spitting out the full file name.

Comment: @EmilyNwo no, it won't. You're doing something wrong but we won't know what until you provide a [mcve].

Comment: try running with `set -vx` or add `declare -p variablename` statements so you can see the values at particular points in the run

Comment: If you are using `sh` to run your script, `${variable/replacement}` won't work; but `${variable%suffix}` will. See also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got (rightfully) admonished for providing an answer that would get the job done but was a bit buggy. So I just deleted the whole disaster and gave it another try. I'm sure the senior contributors on this platform could improve it but this was my best shot. I added in a catches to return messages if paths aren't correct. Feel free to ignore whatever is not useful to you. Hopefully it helps!

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the input directory containing .fastq.gz files
input_dir="/storage/home/user/work/fastq_data"

# Set the output directory for .sam and summary files
output_dir="/storage/home/user/work/fastq_data/gene_alignment"

#Ignore this if you want: I always like to add a little message 
#to let me know whether I typed my paths in wrong :)

#Confirm input path exists
if [ -d "$input_dir" ]; then
        echo "$input_dir found. Continuing..."
else 
        echo "$input_dir does not exist. Exiting..."
        exit
fi

#Confirm *fastq.gz files are in input_dir
if find "$input_dir" -type f -name "*.fastq.gz" -print -quit | grep -q .; then
    echo "Files with .fastq.gz extension exist in $input_dir"
else
    echo "No files with .fastq.gz extension found in $input_dir"
    exit
fi

#Confirm output directory path exists
if [ -d "$output_dir" ]; then
        echo "$output_dir found. Continuing..."
else 
        echo "$output_dir does not exist. Creating new..."
        mkdir -p "$output_dir"
fi

#Again, your choice. I prefer for loops over while loops. Totally your call
for file in `ls ${input_dir}/*.fastq.gz`; do
  filename=$(basename "$file")
  new_name=$(echo "$filename" | sed 's/_R_001//g')
  output_sam="${output_dir}/${new_name/.fastq.gz/.sam}"
  summary_file="${output_dir}/${new_name/.fastq.gz/.summary}"
  hisat2 -p 8 -x musculus_index -U "${input_file}" -S "${output_sam}" --dta-cufflinks 2>&1 | tee "${summary_file}"
  echo "Processed ${file}"
done

echo "Processing complete."
```